# Burninate [unsupported]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsupported) is too general of a tag and doesn't really belong.  88 questions in it right now; most dealing with various random things.  A fair amount deal with Java's `UnsupportedOperationException`, while others with support for different devices and such.

Answer (score 1):

- No experts in unsupporting?
- What is exactly unsupported? Does looking at this tag helps you understand what it is about? Unsupported screen orientation? Unsupported framework? It doesn't add anything.
- Would anyone search for [unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unsupported)? No.
- One follower? Foo.
- 88 questions? Out of 8m questions?

---

Totals:

## <kbd>BURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAGBURNINATETHISTAG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</kbd>

Oh, wait, long kbds are unsupported...

Comment: Apparently really long `<kbd>` tags aren't supported...

Comment: @This thats why I added them ;)