# Tag wiki suggested edit approved but tag wiki is still empty

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Somebody [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5951307) for the [google-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-widget) tag wiki. Despite fitting one of the [new reject reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/239950#239950) perfectly,<sup>*</sup> the edit was approved by three other reviewers.

The same user also [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5951308) for the tag wiki *excerpt*. This edit was rejected.

Now when you navigate to the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-widget/info) page, it says:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!

But if you click on the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26261958/revisions) link, the approved edit is shown as revision 2:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Is this just because there is no excerpt, or is this a bug?

---

* *"This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something useful to this community specifically, and be sure to attribute the original author."*

<sub>Note that I'm not asking about the validity of the edit; I think it was crap so I voted to reject it, and I'm not convinced that the tag itself is even useful.</sub>

Comment: Cool, your huge image inside `<kbd>` broke [my user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch). :) The next release will have some extra CSS to ensure that `<kbd>` elements cannot be wider than the page.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen If you think that's bad, check out [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273099). You can blame Will for this: [How to make images stand out when posting images with whitespace?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270195)

Comment: Heh, the fix I just pushed out makes even nicael's long `<kbd>` wrap nicely. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, as you surmised, because there is no excerpt. Conceptually, the excerpt is *part* of the wiki - and until that part exists, the wiki is considered incomplete and will not be displayed.

This behavior replaces a previous, [rather more severe behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki/80153#80153), and can be found documented on Meta SE:

> There is a slight edge condition:
>
> If somebody submits a tag wiki edit for a blank wiki and only the wiki body is accepted (wiki excerpt rejected) the wiki will still appear blank. No information is lost in this case, and the next editor will see the body.

Comment: I assume the same thing happens when an excerpt is approved but the wiki text is not?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: no, a blank wiki with just a excerpt *is* fine.